# How to add confidence interval ribbon, equation and R2 from a mixed effect regression lmer model in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, lme4, mixed-models

I'm fitting a simple linear linear regression with mixed effects. I want to plot the raw data against the predicted fit (line - (figured this out)), the confidence interval (figured this out), line equation and R2. I know how to do this using `stat_summary` from a general model. I want to learn how to do this for a `lmer`. Here is the code and attempt so far.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(xaxis = rnorm(100, 2, 3), yaxis = rnorm(100,8,3), rfactor = rep(c("A","B","C"), times = 100))

library(lme4)
library(ggplot2)
library(emmeans)

fit <- lmer(yaxis ~ xaxis + (1|rfactor), data= df)
gr <- ref_grid(fit, cov.keep= c('xaxis'))
emm <- emmeans(gr, spec= c('xaxis'), level= 0.95)

summary(fit)$coefficient

Estimate Std. Error  df    t value      Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  7.79653407 0.21741014 298 35.8609497 4.015840e-110
xaxis       -0.05247161 0.06129086 298 -0.8561083  3.926257e-01

ggplot(data= df, aes(x= xaxis, y= yaxis)) + theme_classic() + 
  geom_ribbon(data= data.frame(emm), aes(ymin= lower.CL, ymax= upper.CL, y= NULL), fill= 'grey80') +
  geom_line(data= data.frame(emm), aes(y= emmean)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: check out the `ggeffects` package ...